# Edit multiple Excel workbooks in folder

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a couple hundred CSV files I need to do the same edits to.

-I need to change one column from scientific notation to a number without and decimals

-If a cell in specific column begins with '2014', delete entire row

-Save as new file name, from 'filename.csv' to 'filename_new.csv'

I tried using Kutools for Excel but couldn't figure out if I could edit multiple books

Could someone help me out with this? I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: If purely editing csv files (assuming ascii text), I would use VBS to edit the text rather than Excel. Coding will be much simpler for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

`Workbooks.Open "YourFilePath"` will let you open a single file (don't forget that you'll probably need to store the workbook in a variable so you can better address it).
You can then do whatever edit you like, for example your `YourSheet.Cells(x,y).EntireRow.Delete` under an `If` condition. 
You can then `.Close` your Workbook and specify a filename to save.

Matt, I'm sorry but I can just provide you some ideas. Writing the code won't help you learn :)